# Why does a VS2010 build on a jenkins slave using cygwin give fatal error C1902?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ssh, jenkins, cygwin

I have set up a jenkins slave server with cygwin and I'm launching builds on it via ssh.
The build of our project succeeds if run locally as the slave user both in the windows command prompt and in the cygwin command prompt. I can also ssh into the machine as the slave user and run the build successfully.
However, when jenkins runs the build as that slave, it fails trying to compile the first C++ project with the error: fatal error C1902: Program database manager mismatch; please check your installation.

Visual C++ 2010 express, and Visual C# 2010 express are both installed and required for our project to build.

In my research I found some indications that cygwin does not handle the remote login correctly here: https://java.net/projects/hudson/lists/users/archive/2008-10/message/130

Has anyone else solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution
Use “Launch slave agents via Java Web Start” to add windows slave to jenkins master.
It will launch Jenkins service on windows machine using some local users account. Then change local user to the user you are using to build locally.

The problem with “Launch slave agents on Unix machines as SSH” method is, it runs connection using “cyg_server” user.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Java webstart is a potential alternative, but this question was meant to address the ssh option specifically (there may be reasons why Java Web Start is not desirable). I'll edit the question to make it more clear. Your comment about the user is potentially on track. Could you clarify why you think the "cyg_server" user contributes to the C1902 error?