# "fatal error C1902: Program database manager mismatch; please check your installation " on Cygwin Jenkins Agent via SSH

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-agent

I'm trying to get an msbuild working (Visual C++ 2008) using a vagrant Jenkins agent however I'm running into this error:

```
fatal error C1902: Program database manager mismatch; please check your installation
```

Having looked online ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765854/why-does-a-vs2010-build-on-a-jenkins-slave-using-cygwin-give-fatal-error-c1902) for example) it appears to be some problem with the agent ssh configuration. The response here was to set the agent up to use 'Launch agents via Java Web Start' however I don't appear to have this option. [More research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340097/there-is-no-launch-agent-via-java-web-start-option-in-my-jenkins-when-i-adding) pointed towards setting up a TCP port for the agents. I've tried this (although the answer is now pretty old and out of date), selecting a manual TCP port of 50000. No additional agent options magically appear (even the 'updated' "Launch agent by connecting it to the controller").

I've also tried connecting the agent with all other options with no success (although I am a newbie here)

Any tips? All the material online appears to be at least 5+ years old...

Jenkins version: 2.414.3